# on click event handler questions

Tags: javascript, function, object, average, eventhandler

I am having trouble with a bit of code I am trying to get information to show up on a page with information that is stored in objects. I need to create an onclick event **in JS not HTML**  on the button which, when clicked calls a function that displays the information stored in my object array 
Also when they click through all the students I need to disable the button.

The specific problem I am having is with showing the second object set. It skips directly to the third and I was wondering how to fix this below is my code

I also need to create a function that averages the ratings of the car to show in Avg Rating:

```
var display = document.querySelectorAll('#output div');

var button = document.querySelector('.buttonred');



// There will be no more then 4 global variables.

//Create an array of  objects containing 3 main properties (keys) and 3 sub properties.
var cars =[
   { name: 'ford', address:{street :'12 shoe st',city:'Candyland', state:'HI'}, rating:[4.0, 3.5, 4.0],phone: '555-555-5551'},
   { name: 'honda', address:{street:'45 wii ln',city:'Nashville', state:'TN'}, rating:[2.5, 3.5, 3.0],phone: '323-2343-1232'}
    ];
console.log(cars);


function showCars (cars){
for (var i = 0, j=cars.length; i < j; i++){
    console.log('Name: '+ cars[i].name);
    console.log('Address: '+ cars[i].address.street + ', ' + cars[i].address.city + ', ' + cars[i].address.state);
    console.log('Rating: '+ cars[i].rating);
    console.log('Phone: '+ cars[i].phone);
    }
}

//run the function
showCars(cars);


// Add a new object to the array of objects above
function Car(name,street,city,state,rating,phone){
    this.name=name;
    this.address = {
        street:street,
        city:city,
        state:state
    };
   this.rating = rating;
   this.phone = phone;
}
//Add this new car
cars[2] = new Car('Toyota', '12 Wyatt', 'Heron', 'MT', [3.5, 2.4, 3.6],'000-867-5309');

//Console.log ALL the information in ALL objects on 3 lines.
console.log(cars);
showCars(cars);




//Create an onclick event on the ‘Next’ button which, when clicked calls a function
button.addEventListener("click", onPage, false);

//Show first 
display[0].innerHTML ='Name: '+cars[0].name;
display[1].innerHTML ='Address: '+ cars[0].address.street + ', ' + cars[0].address.city + ', ' + cars[0].address.state;
display[2].innerHTML ='Rating: '+cars[0].rating;
display[4].innerHTML ='Avg rating: '+ 'function here';
display[5].innerHTML ='Phone: ' + cars[0].phone;



// display object data one at a time in the HTML
function onPage(){
for (var ii = 1, jj=cars.length; ii < jj; ii++) {
    if (cars[ii] !== cars[2]) {
        display[0].innerHTML = 'Name: ' + cars[ii].name;
        display[1].innerHTML = 'Address: ' + cars[ii].address.street + ', ' + students[ii].address.city + ', ' + cars[ii].address.state;
        display[2].innerHTML = 'Rating: ' + cars[ii].rating;
        display[4].innerHTML = 'Avg Rating: ' + 'function here';
        display[5].innerHTML = 'Phone: ' + cars[ii].phone;
    } else {
        display[0].innerHTML = 'Name: ' + cars[2].name;
        display[1].innerHTML = 'Address: ' + cars[2].address.street + ', ' + cars[2].address.city + ', ' + cars[2].address.state;
        display[2].innerHTML = 'Rating: ' + cars[2].rating;
        display[3].innerHTML = 'Date: ' + date;
        display[4].innerHTML = 'Avg rating: ' + 'function here';
        display[5].innerHTML = 'Phone: ' + cars[2].phone;
       button.removeEventListener("click", onPage, false);
        button.innerHTML = "Done";
    }


}
}//ends function
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>  

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Car list</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="form_box">
    <div id="contact-form">
        <p class="heading">Display Car Information Below:</p>
        <div id="form-box">                     

                <div id="output">
                    <div id="name">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="address">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="gpa">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="date">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="gpaavg">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="phone">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="clear"></div> -->
                </div>

                <div id="info_box">
                    <div id="info_btn">
                        <h4 id="round" class="heading">Click To See Next Car</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="buttonred">Next</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>


  <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your script. Could you fix them first and let us see the fixed one?

Error 1: Uncaught ReferenceError: cas is not defined: Line 14

```
console.log(cas); // Error
console.log(cars); // Correct
```

Error 2: Uncaught ReferenceError: ratings is not defined: Line 38

```
function Object(name,street,city,state,rating,phone){ // Error
function Object(name,street,city,state,ratings,phone){ // Correct
```

Error 3: Uncaught ReferenceError: students is not defined: Line 59

```
// There was no `students` variable defined in your script.
// Please fix this error.
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't use the name `Object` for function name or variable name because it is a reserved word.

---

There is one more error left.

Error 1: Uncaught ReferenceError: Car is not defined: Line 42

```
function Object(name,street,city,state,rating,phone){
function Car(name,street,city,state,rating,phone){
```

Next, you have to determine which type of data to use for cars; simple Object or Car instance. Your current code has mixed of them. Otherwise, it is difficult to iterate `cars` to show its property.

```
[
  Object/* ford */,
  Object/* honda */,
  Car/* Toyota */
]
```

If you want to use Car instance, you have to initialize `cars` as below

```
var cars = [
  new Car('ford', '12 shoe st', 'Candyland', 'HI', [4.0, 3.5, 4.0], '555-555-5551'),
  new Car('honda', '45 wii ln', 'Nashville', 'TN', [2.5, 3.5, 3.0], '323-2343-1232')
];
```

Or, if you want to use simple Object, please push new entry like below.

```
cars[2] = { name: 'honda', address:{street:'12 Wyatt',city:'Heron', state:'MT'}, rating:[3.5, 2.4, 3.6],phone: '000-867-5309'}
```

---

Convert Array<Object> to Array<Car>

```
// cars = [{Object}, {Object}]

cars = cars.map(function(car) {
  return new Car(car.name, car.address.street, car.address.city, car.address.state, car.rating, car.phone);
});

// cars = [{Car}, {Car}]
```

Comment: @learning2code Now I added further step to my answer. Can you fix your code again?

Comment: Arkaki is there a way to add it to the cars instance using a function?

Comment: @learning2code Please use Array#map. I added example to my answer. This method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. Take care that you have to do this before adding new car.